# Dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu: GRUB Problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I tried to Dual-Boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10. But I can not choose to start Windows, when I turn on my Computer (Lenovo ThinkPad E330).

I can access all my files of Windows from Ubuntu, because they are shown in the file manager as a separate Volume.

I already tried to run Boot-Repair, but that did not help. This is my Boot-Repair Report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14664166/

I hope the issue can be resolved.

Thanks.

-

Comment: Is this a machine you upgraded to W10?  It has an MSDOS partitioned disk, no EFI, and does not look like it is a UEFI machine, so no EFI needed.  Did you ever run Win 10 on it?  Is W10 not hibernated?

Comment: I had W10 running on this machine, if this is what you are asking. Then I tried the Dual Boot with Ubuntu.

Comment: Cautioning against any UEFI related suggestions, since W10 does not necessarily imply UEFI, and your machine is not UEFI.  Did you prepare the W10 side for the install by turning off fast startup (a power option) so the machine is not hibernated?

Comment: No, i didn't. Can this be fixed? I also don't have a Windows Installation CD at hand, so I can't completely remove Windows, even though I have a backup of all my files.

Answer (score 0):

If you can open Ubuntu and access all the files using file manager in ubuntu then you can update your grub using the command in terminal.

```
> sudo update grub
```

Comment: I ran this command, it is actually:

`sudo update-grub` 

But that doesnt change it. I get the boot menu, when I start my Laptop,  but I only get Ubunutu Options (Advanced Options for Ubuntu, Memory Test). 

Can I manually add an entry to this menu?

But to what diretory should I link that? The one where all my data is (/media) or the one where the partion should be (mnt/boot-sav/sda2)?

Answer (score 0):

Searching this site for "hiberfile" gives many answers regarding this problem.  Here's a link with several suggestions:
http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/
  If the mount option remove_hiberfile still works, that is the easiest one to use.  The W8 suggestions are probably applicable to W10.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this situation as well.

The easiest thing to do is to create a backup of your data and format the Windows and Ubuntu partitions, oh yes to install all over again.

If you install Ubuntu and then Windows, Windows will overwrite the MBR, so, first install Windows, then Ubuntu, then GRUB can recognize both systems.

In the tests we did, I worked for both Windows 10 and Windows 7.

Comment: But what did I do wrong the first time? I mean, I had Windows 10 installed and then tried to Dual Boot whit Ubuntu.